# Making a input field readonly using Javascript or Jquery (My code is working on chrome but not on IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, readonly

There is a form on my website and If all the fields are filled out and submitted and again the user tries to access the same form only few fields are displayed and other fields are not as their data is cached. There is one field which needs to be populated with the data entered but should be readonly. My task is to make that field readonly.

This code works on Chrome but not on IE. Please suggest a code which can work on IE to make a field readonly.

Thanks,
Anu

Comment: Hi, It is not the duplicate. In my case I've tried all the solutions posted in the other thread and nothing works. I need to make a cached field readonly, i need add a condition which checks if the input field has a a tag and a href attribute and then if yes apply the readonly to that input element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes using `attr` like so:

```
$('#someid').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

However, for **DOM properties** like `checked`, `disabled` and `readonly`, the proper way to do this **(as of JQuery 1.6)** is to use `prop`.

```
$('#someid').prop('readonly', true);
```

```js
//method 1
$("#input1").attr("readonly","readonly");
//method 2
$("#input2").prop("readonly",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" type="text" />
<input id="input2" type="text" />
```

---

`readonly` input element doesn't work in IE 8,9, 10 or 11.
But you can simulate it using the following method:

```js
$("#myInput").on("keydown", function() {return false});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" value="some value"/>
```

Comment: I've used Prop and it doesn;t work either.

Comment: Ok, will try this but will this code work on other browsers too?. also, in my code  var resetElem = $('.email a[href^="/form/incorrectProspect/account_id/73532"]').val() , if i dont use val() it is adding readonly to the main form field not the catched field, is there anything wrong in the code here?.,

Comment: Hi, I've added this $("#myInput").on("keydown", function() {return false});
 but still, doesn't work on IE but works on chrome.

Answer (score -1):

You must use `.prop()`, not `.attr()` to set readonly. See http://api.jquery.com/prop/
With `.prop()` you should use the boolean value true or false and (as far as I remember) a small o in readonly:

```
$('#Emailpi_Email').prop('readonly', true);
```

Comment: App.emailReadOnly = function () {
        
      var resetElem = $('.email a[href^="/form/incorrectProspect/account_id/73532"]').val();
        
      if (resetElem !== undefined){
         
        $('#Emailpi_Email').prop('readonly', 'true');
          
      }
    }; 

Even using prop doesn't work on IE

Comment: I've just successfully tested it using IE 9 with jquery 2.1.4 using `jQuery('#test').prop('readonly', true)`. Are you sure your filter matches right? Does `$('yourfilter')` show your object? Maybe try with something more obvious like a `.val('test')`?